# PLSQL filtering with certain gap between character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql syntax like below

```
 select distinct FE.parent_entity, FEATTR.attribute_value from F_ENTITY FE
 inner join F_ENTITYATTRIBUTE FEATTR on FEATTR.entity = FE.entity
 where 
 FEATTR.attribute_value like 'PO%V%%B%%%%'
```

The result i expect to get example is:

> **PO***C***V***KL***B***0AB2*

Can please help how do i create the sql syntax to get the expected result?
Because if i do like what i did above, it will get multiple result example are:

> **PO**MN**V**1234**B**1
> **PO**123456**V**ABCDEF**B**12345678
> **PO**ABC**V**ACDEG**B**ANMM123

Comment: please edit the question and show the sample table data.  I don't think multiple %  characters is doing what you expect.,  You probably need to use regexp_like

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Help needed if anyone know how to query to get for the expected result as i mention..i put multiple % because i not sure how do i query it..

Comment: Look at the section "pattern-matching characters" section in [the LIKE documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-0779657B-06A8-441F-90C5-044B47862A0A) for the difference between `%` and `_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of % you should use the _ character in your condition. The _ character in a like condition allows you to match on a single character.

So your SQL should be the following:

```
select distinct FE.parent_entity, FEATTR.attribute_value from F_ENTITY FE
 inner join F_ENTITYATTRIBUTE FEATTR on FEATTR.entity = FE.entity
 where 
 FEATTR.attribute_value like 'PO_V__B%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with what @Kapitany suggested. Though, one more option: regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'POMNV1234B1'              from dual union all
  3     select 'PO123456VABCDEFB12345678' from dual union all
  4     select 'POABCVACDEGBANMM123'      from dual union all
  5     select 'POCVKLB0AB2'              from dual
  6    )
  7  select col
  8  from test
  9  where regexp_like(col, '^PO.{1}V.{2}B.*$');

COL
------------------------
POCVKLB0AB2

SQL>
```

It says: return values that

- start `^` with `PO`
- followed by only one other character `.{1}`
- followed by `V`
- followed by two other characters `.{2}`
- followed by `B`
- ending by zero or any number of other characters, up to the end of the string `.*$`